# Can I send an email to myself when re.compile doesn't find a certain pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, compilation, python-re

Currently, my code goes through my emails and looks for a certain pattern. I wanted to make it so that if an email does not have that pattern, it'll send that email to a certain email. Any help is appreciated :)

```
with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
    # fetch the email message by ID
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            # decode the email subject
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                subject = subject.decode(encoding)
            # decode email sender
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            if isinstance(From, bytes):
                From = From.decode(encoding)
            print("Subject:", subject)
            print("From:", From)

                # iterate over email parts
            for part in msg.walk():
                # extract content type of email
                content_type = part.get_content_type()
                content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                if payload is None:
                    continue
                body = payload.decode()                   
                pattern = re.compile(
                    r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
                    #r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
                    #r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)( Line ([0-9]+))?( Seq ([0-9])? ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
                    #r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)( Line ([0-9]+ )| )(Seq ([0-9]) |)([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)")

                matches = pattern.finditer(body)
                writer.writerows(map(lambda m: m.groups(), matches))
                break
```

imap.close()
imap.logout()

Answer (score 0):

You have a python regex

```
pattern = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
```

and some string

```
body
```

pattern.findall(body) returns the empty list if there are no matches. pattern.match(body) returns None if there are no matches. So

```
if not pattern.findall(body):
    ...  # send email
```

or

```
if pattern.match(body) is None:
    ...  # send email
```

fit your reqs. pattern.finditer(body) always returns an iterator, which is a truthy object; the body of the

```
if not pattern.finditer(body):
```

statement is never executed.

Comment: sweet. so what does that look like altogether?

Comment: I answered your question, I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: sorry.. i don't know Python well. could you please help me?

Comment: nope___________